# Putting Curly braces in a string in C

Tags: c, json, string, printf, ansi-c

I am using a JSON parser with C. The JSON request requires curly braces. I am trying to insert user input into one of the JSON request fields. To do this, I have a variable that stores the first half of the request, a variable for the user input, and a variable for the rest of the JSON request. I use `snprintf` to combine the variables together. I can't seem to get the last curly brace to go through.

```
const char *open_brace = "}}";
    char buf[306];  
    char trackingnum[18];

    char *test = "{\"UPSSecurity\": {\"UsernameToken\": {\"Username\": \"xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.edu\",\"Password\": \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"},\"ServiceAccessToken\": {\"AccessLicenseNumber\": \"8D421B74FBC948C8\"}},\"TrackRequest\": {\"Request\": {\"RequestOption\": \"1\",\"TransactionReference\": {\"CustomerContext\": \"\"}},\"InquiryNumber\": \"";
    char ending[10] = "\"}}";
    strcat (ending, open_brace);

    printf("\nEnter a tracking number: ");
    scanf(" %s",trackingnum);
    printf("\nTracking num is: %s\n",trackingnum);

     snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%s%s%s", test, trackingnum, ending, open_brace );

    printf("\nBuf is: %s\n\n\n\n",buf);
    char *postthis = buf;
```

Output:

```
Enter a tracking number: 1ZY5841YYW90351446

Tracking num is: 1ZY5841YYW90351446

Buf is: {"UPSSecurity": {"UsernameToken": {"Username": "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.edu","Password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},"ServiceAccessToken": {"AccessLicenseNumber": "8D421B74FBC948C8"}},"TrackRequest": {"Request": {"RequestOption": "1","TransactionReference": {"CustomerContext": ""}},"InquiryNumber": "1ZY5841YYW90351446"}




{"Error":{"Code":"4","Description":"JSON Syntax error"}}
jobj from str:
---
{
   "Error": {
     "Code": "4",
     "Description": "JSON Syntax error"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Could you show us some code, and tell us both what you expect to happen and what is happening instead?

Comment: Edited with output and code

Comment: The open and close braces don't match in buf.

Comment: Once I add the ending with snprint f they should

Comment: `char trackingnum[18];` can only hold 17 characters but you enter 18. The terminating nul character might affect your neighboring variables.

Comment: "open_brace" is a somewhat inappropriate name for `"}}"`

Comment: You first append some characters to ending (`strcat (ending, open_brace);`) and then add both in` snprintf.`. It that intentional?

Comment: @Gerhardth It worked! Thanks!

Comment: Were you short of stack space that you couldn't just use "ample" sized arrays?  I'd suggest: `char buf[512];` and `char trackingnum[32];` - strings have nul terminators to indicate the end - there is no need to size buffers to be exactly the number of characters you expect and if you habitually do that you are always going to have these problems as well as rendering your code much harder to maintain and modify for new requirements..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've sized `buf` incorrectly. Since you're using `snprintf`, it's truncating the text you're putting in so that it fits in the available space.

A better way to do what you're trying to do is to use `malloc` as then you can specify the correct size for `buf` like this:

```
char *buf = malloc(strlen(test) + strlen(trackingnum) + strlen(ending) + strlen(open_brace)+1);
sprintf(buf, "%s%s%s%s", test, trackingnum, ending, open_brace );
```

You can then also use `sprintf` as you know that the combined length of the strings plus the extra space for the NUL character will fit.

And once you've done with `buf`, don't forget to `free` it.

You should also make sure that the amount entered into `trackingnum` isn't more than it's able to hold too.

Comment: @Gerhardh are you sure? I copied the string into an editor and it came to 305 characters

Comment: I just changed them to buf[350] and trackingnum[19]

Comment: @ChrisTurner : Which string?  `buf` is only 287, `test` is shorter than the source code string because `\"` is one character.

Comment: I copied the text from the output as that includes all the various strings combined

Comment: @ChrisTurner : Weird; so did I and it is still 287.

Comment: Ahhh...it looks like whilst I was typing in my answer the question was updated such that the contents of `buf` were altered to hide the username & password

Comment: @CryptoCat : If you want to change the code to hide sensitive data, you need to at least use the same number of characters - your question now no longer exhibits the problem, because it is not the code you are running.  This is bad form on SO.  The sensitive data is still there however - we can all look at the edit-history - you might want to change your passwords... and your school!

Comment: @ChrisTurner Sorry about that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have edited the question to restore the string length so that this answer now makes sense.